# jquery two different trigger with same class

Tags: javascript, events, triggers, jquery

i have two tag, which has same class but different trigger events, following is example:

```
<a class="remove">remove this</a>
<div class="status"><a class="remove">Remove this status div only</a></div>

in jquery i have it like
$(".remove").live('click', function()... (this gets trigger for both)
$(".status_update > .remove").live('click', function()...  (i want this to trigger for status div remove link)
```

i need to do this in two different triggers, cant do it in same trigger call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".remove").live('click', function() {
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass('status_update')) // execute inner links code
  else // execute outer links code
});
```

Comment: need to do this in two different calls

Comment: I think you will need to assign different class name for that. If you write $('.remove') it will always apply on all elements with class remove. If you don't want to change class name only to do it is have a check in function

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the clicked anchor's parent's class name is `.status` and act accordingly, using either [`.unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) or [`.remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
$("a.remove").live('click', function() {
   if($(this).parent().hasClass("status")) { // or $(this).parent('.status').length
       $(this).unwrap("div.status");
   } else {
       $(this).remove();
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks karim for the answer, but i need to do this in two different calls, cant do it in one call, because one is global and other is sub section which changes to every different page.

Comment: @Basit - I'm a little lost. Do you mean `.unwrap` and `.remove` are what you need, only in the two event handlers in your question? Or is there some other problem?

Comment: @Basit - Why do you need two event handlers when a single one can take care of both link types using a conditional? Is there a special reason for that?

Comment: yes. i have two different javascript file. one is global and second is by the section. each section has there own file (media, feed...). so i cant put things in global file, need to keep them separate, which will keep things neat and easy to modify, remember and proper way.

Comment: Then for your second 'section' event handler, instead of `$("status_update > .remove")` use another selector like `$("status_update > a").live("...` to avoid confusion?

Comment: i have other links there too, in the status update, so that was just an example code in the question.